# how to add a comment on the first cell where a specific value is found and loop it

Tags: vba, excel

The end goal of the macro is to search if there is a value in column D starting at row 20, If TRUE then search for the first "TT" of the row and add a comment (value found in column D). 
Then do it for the first TF and FT of the row that same row. 
Then go on the next row until it reach row 499.

I am able to find the address of the cell with the specified value.

I am able to create a macro that writes the comment.

what I don't know how to mix them both together and apply the loop correctly to go through all the column.

Thanks!

Here a data Sample:

[image: Data sample]

The cells in teal should get a comment. That comment is the value found in the cell on the same row in column D

Here is the code I got right now:

```
Sub Add_Comments()

Dim rng As Range
Dim taskname As Long

'Turns off Conditional formating
Range("D1").Value = "NOCF"
Application.Wait Now + #12:00:02 AM#


For taskname = 20 To 499
'Checks if there is a task on that row
If Not IsEmpty(cell.Offset(taskname, 4).Value) Then
'Start the loop to find and comment cells if value = TT, TF or FT
    Set rng = cell.Offset(taskname, 4)
    Set taskcmt = Selection.Find(What:="TT", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not taskcmt Is Nothing Then
'Add a comment on the current address
        Cells(taskname, taskcmt.Column).AddComment rng.Value

        End If
'Turns on conditional formating
Else: Range("D1").Value = "CF"
Exit Sub
End If

Next
'Turns on conditional formating
Range("D1").Value = "CF"
End Sub
```

I also posted that question on 2 other sites

Here are the links:

https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1051202-how-add-comment-first-cell-where-specific-value-found-loop.html#post5047803

and

https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-vba-macros/1202240-how-to-add-a-comment-on-the-first-cell-where-a-specific-value-is-found-and-loop-it

Comment: Please show us the code you tried. It is not clear what you mean by TT TF and FT, are those columns or text? If text, what do you mean by the first TT?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended doing it. One macro for each posibility ("TT", ""TF", "FT")
I am pretty sure this could be cleaned up and I could probably change the "FIND" to look for TT, then TF and finally FT but it was easier to duplicate the macro, erase what should only be done at the beginning or at the end and call the next macro so they could run one after the other.

```
Sub Add_Comments_TF()

Dim taskname As String
Dim taskrng As Long

Turns off Conditional formating
Range("D1").Value = "NOCF"
Application.Wait Now + #12:00:02 AM#

Cells(20, 27).Resize(499, 1104).Select
Selection.ClearComments

For taskrng = 20 To 499

'Checks if there is a task on that row
    Cells(taskrng, 4).Select
    If Cells(taskrng, 4).Value <> "" Then
'Keeping task name in memory
    taskname = Cells(taskrng, 4)
'Start the loop to find and comment cells if value = TT, TF or FT
        Cells(taskrng, 27).Resize(, 1104).Select
        Selection.Find(What:="TF", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Select
        On Error Resume Next
        'Add a comment on the current selection
        Selection.AddComment taskname

    Else:
    End If

Next


Turns on conditional formating
Range("D1").Value = "CF"

Cells(1, 1).Select

Call Add_Comments_TT

End Sub
```